# Filter on a Total Field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

***Edit*** As suggested to me below, I wasn't filtering the visibility on the rows.  Having done this using the below line, I realize its not quite  working properly

```
=IIF(Fields!Number.value = 0, True,False)

             2014   2015 2016 Total
Employee A    12     5     7    24
Employee B     0     0     0     0
Employee C    10    11     1    22
Employee D     0    12     3    15
Employee C     0     0     0     0
```

What's happening is its taking out the Totals with zeros (which I want), but for some reason it is also taking out the first one in the list

```
             2014   2015 2016 Total
Employee A    12     5     7    24 -- This one has disappeared as well
Employee C    10    11     1    22
Employee D     0    12     3    15
```

**Original Question**
I have a matrix with the fields Employee, Year and Number, as below. The Total column has been added on in SSRS (Its not a field in my query)

```
             2014   2015 2016 Total
Employee A    12     5     7    24
Employee B     0     0     0     0
Employee C    10    11     8    29
Employee D     0    12     3    15
Employee C     0     0     0     0
```

I would like to filter out the Totals which have zeros

Tried in the visibility section to show only when
    =IIF(Fields!Total.value  = 0, True,False)

Which does this:

```
             2014   2015 2016 Total
Employee A    12     5     7    24
Employee B    
Employee C    10    11     8    29
Employee D     0    12     3    15
Employee C
```

I would like the outcome to be

```
            2014   2015 2016 Total
Employee A    12     5     7    24
Employee C    10    11     8    29
Employee D     0    12     3    15
```

Comment: it looks like you have set the visibility at the cell level. In design mode, right click the row header on the left and choose 'row visibility'. That show/hide the entire row.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much